# firebase Cloud Functions Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm tring to get stock data from an api.

and I want it be updated at every 12:00 PM.

but when I tring to deploy this funtions, using

> $firebase deploy --only functions

the error comes out.

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
> generate manifest from function source: RangeError: Maximum call stack
> size exceeded

This is "index.ts" in funtions/src.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import axios from "axios"
import { doc, getFirestore, setDoc, Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***********",
    authDomain: "****",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

const API_KEY = "****************"

interface Wow {
    clpr: string
    srtnCd: string
}

const today = new Date();
const yesterday = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
const basDt = format(yesterday, 'yyyyMMdd')

export const getStocks = functions
    .region('asia-northeast3')
    .pubsub.schedule('12 00 * * *')
    .timeZone('Asia/Seoul').onRun(async (context) => {
        await axios.get(`https://api.odcloud.kr/api/GetStockSecuritiesInfoService/v1/getStockPriceInfo?numOfRows=3000&resultType=json&basDt=${basDt}&serviceKey=${API_KEY}`)
            .then(response => {
                const wow: Wow[] = response.data.response.body.items.item
                wow.map((v, index) => {
                    setDoc(doc(db, 'KRX', v.srtnCd), { day: Timestamp.fromDate(today), price: v.clpr })
                })
                return null;
            })
    })
```

Another functions do work well .
but if I include this one, It doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious right now, but as some other notes: 1) `Date#setDate` **mutates** the `Date` object it is called on, it also returns a number, not the `Date` object. 2) `setDoc` is asynchronous. You should be keeping track of the promise it returns and waiting for all of them to resolve. Your database updates might be cancelled if you don't. 3) Use `firebase-admin` rather than `firebase` for Cloud Functions. 4) Consider swapping out `axios` for `gaxios` or `node-fetch` as both are already used by the Firebase SDKs. 5) Share the `day` timestamp object between `setDoc` calls.

Comment: @samthecodingman I firstly used the `firebase-admin` but types are not matched with `firestore` `doc` or `setDoc`. It said `doc` needs `Firebase` but `FirebaseFirestore.Firestore` is in.

Comment: Ah right, I thought that they would have fixed that by now. Unfortunately the `firebase-admin/firestore` package is basically `@google-cloud/firestore` under the hood and aside from `getFirestore()`, you need to use the legacy namespaced syntax for it. It is important to switch to the admin package though as the client SDK isn't properly compatible with Node.js and it is also affected by rate limiting which will bite you later down the track.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because this is your `functions\src\index.ts` file, you should only be exporting Cloud Functions from it and nothing else.

So change:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

to:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

If you want to export an initialized Firebase SDK for use elsewhere, move it to its own file called `functions\src\firebase.ts` (or similar):

```
// firebase.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

export const app = initializeApp(); // no arguments uses the default service account
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

then use it like so:

```
import { app, db } from "./firebase.ts"

// NOTE: at time of writing, @google-cloud/firestore still uses the legacy namespaced syntax
db.doc("path/to/some/document") 
  .set({ /* data */ })
  .then(() => console.log('success'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('error', err));
```