# "Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" from firebase function taken from official site

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This code snippet is taken from the official site except I removed the check for admin role as no one has it yet. Unfortunately I get "Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error still. Assuming it's from the official site it should work.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

async function grantAdminRole(email) {
  //Fetches the user.
  const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);

  //Checks if the user is already admin.
  if (user.customClaims && user.customClaims.admin === true) {
    return;
  }

  //Sets the user's custom claim admin property to true.
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
    admin: true,
  });
}

exports.addAdmin = functions
  .region("europe-central2")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (context.auth) {
      return {
        context: context,
        data: data,
        error:
          "Request not authorized. User must be admin to fulfill request. ",
      };
    }

    //Grants the user with the email admin role.
    const email = data.email;
    return grantAdminRole(email).then(() => {
      return {
        result: `Request fulfilled. Successfully added ${email} as admin. `,
      };
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace

Comment: You are probably encountering the problem described by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798651/3068190). Check all the objects you attach to `exports` and make sure that only Cloud Functions are exported from your `index.js` file.

Comment: Additionally, your code sends an error if the user is logged in - you probably meant to check `!context.auth || !context.auth.token.admin` instead (you also might want to log these failed attempts as an audit trail). Don't reflect `context` back to the client as it contains a lot of sensitive information - like the user's decrypted authentication token! - log it instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by returning context:context